# call ngOnDestroy programmatically on design time component in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am showing an custom component("my-addmodule") inside the modal Dialog custom component( "my-modal-dialog") as below,

```
<my-modal-dialog [showFooter]="false" #addModuleDialog>

    <my-addmodule (hideDialog)="hideAddModalDialog($event)" (reloadGrid)="reload($event)" #addModule></my-addmodule>

  </div>
</my-modal-dialog>
```

Now the problem is that, each time, I close the modal dialog, angular is not destroying "my-addmodule" component. So when I open the modal-dialog again, I see the same state of "my-addmodule" component ( some drop-down selection and previously entered value in textbox etc). 
I want angular to destroy component when I close the modal-dialog and re-create the component on opening the modal-dialog.

I tried adding the below code ""my-addmodule" component,

```
export class AddModuleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 public destroyComponent(){
    this.ngOnDestroy();
  }
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Add module is destroyed");
  }
}
```

but when I call "destroyComponent" function on the modal-dialog hide() function, I get error **"this.addModuleDialog.destroyComponent is not a function"**.

following is my parent component ts file, who is using above mentioned two component,
ParentComponent.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements {

  @ViewChild('addModuleDialog') addModuleDialog;
  @ViewChild('addModule') addModule;

showAddModuleDialog(e: any): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.addModuleDialog.show();
  }

  hideAddModalDialog(e: any): void {
    this.addModuleDialog.hide();
    this.addModule.destroyComponent();
  }
}
```

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<my-modal-dialog [showFooter]="false" #addModuleDialog>

        <my-addmodule (hideDialog)="hideAddModalDialog($event)" (reloadGrid)="reload($event)" #addModule></my-addmodule>

      </div>
    </my-modal-dialog>
```

Comment: Your `this.addModuleDialog` variable is a reference to your `my-modal-dialog` component and not the `my-addmodule` component. It looks like your `destroyComponent` method therefore will not exist on the property you are trying to call it on.

Comment: @ Daniel W Strimpel: you are right. Now I have updated my code and  now destroying the "my-addmodule" component explicitely and do not see any errors. But the component state is still maintained. means when I open the "my-modal-dialog" component, it loads the old state of  "<my-addmodule>" component. although ngOnDestroy() function, of <my-addmodule> component,  is being called each time we hide the "<my-addmodule>"  component.  Am I missing anything here??

Comment: In order to get the `my-addmodule` to be disposed when the modal is closed you should probably hold onto a variable keeping track of if the modal is opened. Once you have a variable with that, you can use an `*ngIf` on the `my-addmodule` that will create and destroy the component as the modal opens and closes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please write this as an answer so I can accept it?